# Is it difficult to get a C1 visa from Ghana?

Tags: transit

I am traveling from Ghana to Jamaica and it looks like the cheapest flights are through the US.  I just learned and applied for a C1 visa but I am worried it will not be approved.  How difficult is it to obtain a C1 visa?  I have proof of roundtrip ticket and my outbound has a long layover in the US, but my return does not have a stop over in the US.